# How can i get only the four corners of a rotated rectangle?

Tags: python, opencv

i'm using this code to detect the four corners of a rectangle but due to the pixels waves i get the output below which means i get many points how can i get only the 4 corners (topRight, topLeft, bottomRight, bottomLeft) and not all pixels waves ?

**Note** i'm using opencv with python

```py
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
low_red1 = np.array([0,70,25])
high_red1 = np.array([10,255,255])

low_red2 = np.array([160,70,25])
high_red2 = np.array([180,255,255])

mask0 = cv2.inRange(hsv, low_red1, high_red1)
mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, low_red2, high_red2)
mask = mask0+mask1
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)

contours,_ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,200,0),1)

for c in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.009 * cv2.arcLength(c, True), True)    
    cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], 0, (255, 0, 0), 1)
    n = approx.ravel()
    k = 0
    for j in n :
        if(k % 2 == 0):
            x = n[k]
            y = n[k + 1]
            cv2.circle(img, (x,y), 3, (255, 0, 0), -1)    
        k = k+1

cv2.imshow("corners", img)
```

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91dSB.png)

Comment: See cv2.minAreaRect() to get the rotated rectangle corner points

Comment: @fmw42 but they re not exactly rectangles, they re paralelogram so minAreaRect will not draw an exactly fit rectangle

Comment: @fmw42 i tried to use this function it gives me the four corners but these are not always the exact points but thank you it helped me

Comment: You could search in the neighborhood for pixels on the rectangles and find the max and min values to located corner points. Also see corner detection at  https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga1d6bb77486c8f92d79c8793ad995d541

Comment: okay thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Except when the rectagle is perfectly aligned with your `u` and `v` axis (which you can check), the corners are always the individual `max()` and `min()` values along either `u` or `v` coordinate.